# Best practices to keep up a diverging branch of code

Tags: version-control, open-source

I'm in a situation where some minor patches I've submitted to an open-source project were ignored or explicitly not accepted.
I consider them useful, but more important is that I **need** the functionality they implement.

I don't want to push my ideas and suggestions anymore to the main contributors, because I don't want to turn this into an ego issue. I've decided that my best bet would be just to use what I wrote for my own purposes. I don't want to fork the whole source code tree because I like how things are generally working, I'm just not happy with details.

But I do realize that the project will evolve and I would like to use the new features that will eventually appear. I understand that I'll have to merge all new things into my own source tree. Are there any best practices for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Git](http://git-scm.com/), or could get used to use it, perhaps you should take a look at [Stacked Git](http://www.procode.org/stgit/) or [Guilt](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jsipek/guilt/).

They are layers on top of Git to keep track of patches.

Comment: This is only really useful in terms of git.  what about the rest of us?

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach is to maintain a vendor branch in your repository. The idea is that you import a pristine copy of the original sources (called a *vendor drop*) into your local repository, and store it on a branch. This is the version of the code prior to applying your mods. You tag that with the version, then copy it to the main trunk and apply your patches.

When subsequent new versions of the vendor code are released, you check out the vendor branch (without your mods), and overlay the new version on top. Finally you merge the new branch with your mods, checking that they are still applicable/relevant, and you're ready to go again.

There can be complications e.g. with files being renamed, deleted etc. The script `svn_load_dirs.pl`, that comes with Subversion, can help with this by allowing you to identify files which have changed name and automating some of the bureaucracy.

This approach is discussed in detail (and much more clearly) in the Subversion book, under the section [Vendor Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would create a branch of the project in the repository. In your specific case, I would create a branch of just the directory that contains your code if that is possible. A lot of repositories like subversion will allow you to then check out your branch along side the main trunk. That should allow you to maintain your patches and ensure that they work with future changes that are made to the trunk.